# SwiftUI MVVM how to show alert after a function

Tags: swift, xcode, mvvm, swiftui

I am creating a user login page using MVVM architecture and I want to show an alert page if text field is empty or if wrong username / wrong password. So after login click and API call, if login failed, I want to show an alert, however I tried changing the state but still the alert does not show.

LoginView

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @ObservedObject var user: User
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = LoginViewModel()
    @State var inputUser: String = ""
    @State var inputPass: String = ""
    @State private var showingAlert = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Group {
                    Text("Login")
                    CustomTextField(placeHolder: "Username", value: $viewModel.user)
                    CustomTextField(placeHolder: "Password", value: $viewModel.pass)
                    Button(action: {
                        self.viewModel.login { (isSuccess) in
                            if isSuccess {
                                self.user.tokenIsActive = true
                            } else {
                                // if login failed, show alert, but alert not showing
                                self.showingAlert = true
                            }
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("Sign In")
                    }.buttonStyle(PrimaryButtonStyle())
                    .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                        Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text("Invalid username / password"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LoginViewModel

```
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject, LoginService {
    var apiSession: APIService
    
    @Published var user = ""
    @Published var pass = ""
    
    @Published var accessToken: String?
    @Published var refreshToken: String?
    @Published var showingAlert = true
    
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(apiSession: APIService = APISession()) {
        self.apiSession = apiSession
    }
    
    func login(_ completion: @escaping ((Bool)->Void)) {
        let cancellable = self.loginUser(user: user, pass: pass)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { result in
                switch result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Handle error: \(error)")
                case .finished:
                    break
                }
                
            }) { (result) in
                completion(true)
                self.accessToken = result.accessToken
                self.refreshToken = result.refreshToken
                UserDefaults.standard.set(self.accessToken, forKey: "AccessToken")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(self.refreshToken, forKey: "RefreshToken")
        }
        cancellables.insert(cancellable)
    }
}
```

How do I show the alert? Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your flow the issue is in login logic

```
let cancellable = self.loginUser(user: user, pass: pass)
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)        // << add also this one !!
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { result in
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Handle error: \(error)")
            completion(false)               // << here !!
        case .finished:
            break
        }
        
    }) { (result) in
        self.accessToken = result.accessToken
        self.refreshToken = result.refreshToken
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.accessToken, forKey: "AccessToken")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.refreshToken, forKey: "RefreshToken")
        completion(true) // obviously should be called here !!
                         // and if result is provided always, ie. for 
                         // failed login as well, then conditional
                         // completion should be called.
}
```